# Check if string is anagram of palindrome

Tags: c#, palindrome, anagram

My question is:
How do you check if a given string is the anagram of a palindrome?

I found some solutions in Python on the internet, but I'm not sure how can I check this yet. I was thinking about converting the strig to a `char []`, and then get the HashCode for every character, but I'm stuck.

Comment: Could you give some examples of what you mean? For example, is "abcabc" valid, in that it's an anagram of "abccba" even though neither of them are real words?

Comment: i.e. "naa" is the anagram of "ana" palindrome

Comment: Why would need to get the HashCode for every character and not use the character itself?

Comment: Right, so it doesn't matter whether or not they're really words? That sounds like the check is just "at most one letter occurs an odd number of times".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're not interested in the palindrome or anagram being a real word then I think you can reframe the problem as *check if a given string has no more than one character that appears an uneven number of times*. This is on the basis that only the middle character can possibly occur an odd number of times. As long as that is satisfied then you can form a palindrome from the string.

To do that you can use Linq. Something like this perhaps:

```
private static bool IsPalindromeAnagram(string test)
{
    var charCount = test.GroupBy(c => c, (c, i) => new
        {
            character = c,
            count = i.Count()
        });

    return charCount.Count(c => c.count % 2 == 1) <= 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Saved char in a dictionary as key, then check if more than one key is odd. this way also have all unique char ready to make anagram.

```
 var length = s.Length;

        if (length == 0) return false;

        var dic = new Dictionary<char, int>();

        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {

            if (dic.ContainsKey(s[i]))
            {
                dic[s[i]]++;
                continue;
            }

            dic.Add(s[i], 1);
        }
        int odd = 0;
        foreach (var pv in dic)
        {
            if (odd > 1) return false;
            if (pv.Value % 2 == 0)
            {
                continue;
            }
            odd++;
        }
```